# Python: folder creation when copying files

Tags: python, directory, copy

I'm trying to create a shell script that will copy files from one computer (employee's old computer) to another (employee's new computer). I have it to the point where I can copy files over, thanks to the lovely people here, but I'm running into a problem - if I'm going from, say, this directory that has 2 files:

C:\Users\specificuser\Documents\Test Folder
....to this directory...
C:\Users\specificuser\Desktop
...I see the files show up on the Desktop, but the folder those files were in (Test Folder) isn't created.

Here is the copy function I'm using:

```
#copy function
def dir_copy(srcpath, dstpath):
    #if the destination path doesn't exist, create it
    if not os.path.exists(dstpath):
        os.makedir(dstpath)
    #tag each file to the source path to create the file path
    for file in os.listdir(srcpath):
        srcfile = os.path.join(srcpath, file)
        dstfile = os.path.join(dstpath, file)
        #if the source file path is a directory, copy the directory
        if os.path.isdir(srcfile):
            dir_copy(srcfile, dstfile)
        else: #if the source file path is just a file, copy the file
            shutil.copyfile(srcfile, dstfile)
```

I know I need to create the directory on the destination, I'm just not quite sure how to do it.

Edit: I found that I had a type (os.makedir instead of os.mkdir). I tested it, and it creates directories like it's supposed to. HOWEVER I'd like it to create the directory one level up from where it's starting. For example, in Test Folder there is Sub Test Folder. It has created Sub Test Folder but won't create Test Folder because Test Folder is not part of the dstpath. Does that make sense?

Comment: @PaulK. I already do that as the first thing the function does. However, I think the issue is that my "destination" is Desktop - I'm not specifying Desktop\Test Folder as the destination, so test folder never gets created.

Comment: I apologize, I didnt see that. So the issue is that the copy is not working recursively?

Comment: @PaulK.I edited my original post, but the real issue is that I want it to go one level up from where I start. If I take everything in Documents\Test Folder, and move it to the Desktop, I want it to create Desktop\Test Folder as well, even though technically I didn't specify the destination as Desktop\Test Folder, I specified Desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look at [shutil.copytree()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/shutil.html). It performs the recursive copy functionality, including directories, that you're looking for. So, for a basic recursive copy, you could just run:

```
shutil.copytree(srcpath, dstpath)
```

However, to accomplish your goal of copying the source directory to the destination directory, creating the source directory inside of the destination directory in the process, you could use something like this:

```
import os
import shutil

def dir_copy(srcpath, dstdir):
    dirname = os.path.basename(srcpath)
    dstpath = os.path.join(dstdir, dirname)
    shutil.copytree(srcpath, dstpath)
```

Note that your `srcpath` must not contain a slash at the end for this to work. Also, the result of joining the destination directory and the source directory name must not already exist, or copytree will fail.

Comment: I'm getting "Access is denied" - is there a way to run shutil with elevated permissions or something? Maybe have the user insert the username and password for the computer administrator?

Comment: @MasterModnar if you run the script with administrator permissions, you should not get an access denied error. I honestly don't know much about programming python on Windows, though. If you're getting a write error, you might consider updating permissions on the target folder, rather than running as an admin. You could also `except IOError`, and if the errno is 13 (permission denied), possibly use a different target.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem with file copy... do you intend to just copy the contents of the folder or do you want the folder itself copied. Copy utilities typically have a flag for this and you can too. I use `os.makedirs` so that any intermediate directories are created also.

```
#copy function
def dir_copy(srcpath, dstpath, include_directory=False):
    if include_directory:
        dstpath = os.path.join(dstpath, os.path.basename(srcpath))
    os.makedirs(dstpath, exist_ok=True)
    #tag each file to the source path to create the file path
    for file in os.listdir(srcpath):
        srcfile = os.path.join(srcpath, file)
        dstfile = os.path.join(dstpath, file)
        #if the source file path is a directory, copy the directory
        if os.path.isdir(srcfile):
            dir_copy(srcfile, dstfile)
        else: #if the source file path is just a file, copy the file
            shutil.copyfile(srcfile, dstfile)
```

Comment: What does 'include_directory' do for the function, and why did you set it to 'False'? Also, can you explain 'exist_ok=True' to me?

Comment: `include_directory` changes the algorithm to create the basename of `srcpath` ("Temp Folder") in the destination before copying files. `os.makedirs` and will create multiple subdirectories (suppose dstpath was "C:\Users\specificuser\Desktop\test1\copiedfiles" which needed to be created) and `exist_ok` doesn't raise an error if the directory is already there (no need for os.path.exists test). On the first call, set `include_directory=True` but the later recursive calls don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import shutil
import os

def dir_copy(srcpath, dstpath):
    try:
        shutil.copytree(srcpath, dstpath)
    except shutil.Error as e:
        print('Directory not copied. Error: %s' % e)
    except OSError as e:
        print('Directory not copied. Error: %s' % e)


dir_copy('/home/sergey/test1', '/home/sergey/test2')
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this script to backup (copy) my working folder. It will skip large files, keep folder structure (hierarchy) and create destination folders if they don't exist.

```
import os
import shutil


for root, dirs, files in os.walk(the_folder_copy_from):
   for name in files:
      if os.path.getsize(os.path.join(root, name))<10*1024*1024:
          target=os.path.join("backup", os.path.relpath(os.path.join(root, name),start=the_folder_copy_from))
          print(target)
          os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(target),exist_ok=True)
          shutil.copy(src=os.path.join(root, name),dst=target)

print("Done")
```